# Powershell inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, powershell, extensibility

Does anyone know of a way I can run a powershell within Visual Studio.

By that I mean, have an interactive powershell prompt in a tool window?

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: I'm veeeeeeeery curious to see if someone's able to get a PowerShell prompt running inside VS2010, AND to see what VS-specific objects it has available to it.

Answer (score 42):

The [NuGet Package Manager](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/overview) has a [NuGet Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) which is a **PowerShell** host. Open the console by clicking *Tools* > *Library Package Manager* > *Package Manager Console*.

The package manager is *automatically* installed in Visual Studio 2010 when you install [ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3). You can install ASP.NET MVC 3 using the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). You can also install NuGet by using the Visual Studio *Extension Manager*.

Quoted from the ASP.NET web site:

> ASP.NET MVC 3 automatically installs and enables NuGet as part of its setup. NuGet is a free open-source package manager that makes it easy to find, install, and use .NET libraries and tools in your projects. —http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#overview

Comment: "This package manager is installed by default in Visual Studio 2010." - Is this really true?

Comment: I think so, I was trying to figure it out, but was unable to find any documentation. I'm speaking out of my own experience. I hope to confirm this.

Comment: I thought I had to install NuGet after installing Visual Studio 2010. If I am wrong, please, forgive me for the false alarm.

Comment: Followup note: this IS a powershell window, but it will not load any of your personal profile scripts from the look of it...just garden-variety powershell

Answer (score 8):

There are two very interesting project available:

- A powershell command shell called Power Console:
  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3
- The integration of the PowerGui script editor (the best!) into Visual Studio: http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/

Check them out, together they will fulfill all you needs:-)

Comment: Forget Power Console, the new kid on the block is NuGet (http://nuget.codeplex.com) which has the Power Console integrated.

Comment: Actually these plugins work only for visual studio 2010 and up, while the question is clearly tagged with visual-studio-2008.

Answer (score 3):

Check Out [PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597). It adds language support for PowerShell in Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to View -> Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I use the nuget package manager console as it's already installed in my IDE as part of nuget.

If you use a profile to set up your session environment, be aware that the Nuget profile script name is "NuGet_profile.ps1" located default in $Home\documents\WindowsPowerShell

One thing to be aware of when using PS in Visual Studio: **VS is (currently) a 32 bit application and as such you will not be able to load or invoke the functionality of any 64 bit PS Modules** - for instance the SqlServerManagementModules